# Redirect Loop with SSL for custom domain on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have setup SSL for a custom domain on my Google App engine.
https://master-console.hkmci.com

I want to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS for our custom domain on app engine. 
I setup below code in config file but I get the error message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Are there any ways to solve it?

Thanks.